# Pyqt5 is installed but gives dll failed to load error on import?

Tags: python, c++, windows, qt

So, I tried to install PyQt5(version 5.7.1) for my miniconda3(python version 3.5.1) with `pip install PyQt5` and it shows up when I try `conda list` in console:

[image]

But no pyqt5 program is running and when I import something like:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

its gives an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix this? Do I have to install C++ and Qt lib for C++ for this to work?? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, i've found solution that worked for me, maybe it will be useful for somebody else.

```
conda list
```

should contain `pyqt` `PyQt5` and `qt`. If any of it are not there, you need to install it - run:

`conda install qt`, for example.

I see in the question there is `pyqt` and `PyQt5` installed, but is there qt?